# Retrieve my phone contacts lost in previous phone

Tags: google-account

Please send me _ how to ? I don't want to lose info stored on lost phone

Answer (score 1):

#### If you backed up your contacts to Google:

(You have tagged the question with *Google-account* tag, so I'm assuming that you have stored the contacts there.)

First, make sure you actually have saved your contacts to Google. To do so, go to [contacts.google.com](http://contacts.google.com) and log into your Google account. If you see your contacts there, then follow the steps below:

Go into your phone settings → accounts → Google → sync, and make sure that *contacts* sync, is *on*, if it's on, but the last sync date was a long time ago, make sure to refresh sync. Your contacts should now appear in the contacts app.

#### If you have not backed up your contacts to Google:

If you checked in [contacts.google.com](http://contacts.google.com) and the contacts are not there, that would mean that you have saved the contacts to the internal memory of your lost phone, and in that case there's not much you can do to get them back.